# Scraping a table using python

Tags: python

I am looking to scrape the history table from this website (https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KNYSENEC1#history/tdata/s20171104/e20171104/mdaily) and just print it for now.

Here is the code I have:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-
station/dashboard?ID=KNYSENEC1#history/tdata/s20171104/e20171104/mdaily")   

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    print(record.text)
```

For some reason the table is not being printed, however when I plug in other URL's into this code, tables are scraped no problem.  I am very new to webscraping so I'm sure there is an obvious solution to my issue, I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Before scraping the page have a look at its source code. Here you would notice that the table is generated dynamically from a JSON object stored in a `<script>` block at the end of the HTML document.

Comment: Okay, I see that now.  Since the table is generated dynamically does this mean I can't scrape it?  Or can I make adjustments to my code to account for this.  Thank you for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use something to process the javascript on the page so that it generates the HTML you are trying to parse, or a far better solution is to extract the JSON that is present in the HTML that is returned and use that directly. This can be done as follows:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KNYSENEC1#history/tdata/s20171104/e20171104/mdaily").read().decode('utf8')
json_data = re.findall(r'pws_bootstrap:(.*?)\s+,\s+country\:', html, re.S)
data = json.loads(json_data[0])

for days in data['history']['days']:
    for obs in days['observations']:
        print(obs['date']['iso8601'], obs['temperature'], obs['pressure'], obs['dewpoint'])
```

The hardest part is creating a suitable regular expression to get the start and end of the required JSON.

This would give you an output starting:

```
2017-11-04T00:03:00-0400 3.1 1025.3 1.9
2017-11-04T00:08:00-0400 3.1 1025.3 1.9
2017-11-04T00:13:00-0400 3.0 1025.3 2.0
2017-11-04T00:18:00-0400 2.9 1025.3 1.9
2017-11-04T00:23:00-0400 2.8 1025.3 1.8
```

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to add additional obs in the print line how might I do that?  I tried adding obs['wind'] to get the wind direction, but got a keyerror.  How did you get the temperature, pressure and dewpoint to print?

Comment: Add `print(obs.keys())` and it will show you the available keys you can use. You're probably looking for `obs['wind_dir_degrees']`